# redirect to html page in truffle 'app.js'

Tags: web3js, truffle, ethereumjs

For pet-Dapp http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop , I created a new html page which displays adopted pets. Method I followed is :

**app.js**

```
 App = {
 web3Provider: null,
 contracts: {},

init: function() {
// Load pets.
$.getJSON('../pets.json', function(data) {
  var petsRow = $('#petsRow');
  var petTemplate = $('#petTemplate');

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
    petTemplate.find('.panel-title').text(data[i].name);
    petTemplate.find('img').attr('src', data[i].picture);
    petTemplate.find('.pet-breed').text(data[i].breed);
    petTemplate.find('.pet-age').text(data[i].age);
    petTemplate.find('.pet-location').text(data[i].location);
    petTemplate.find('.btn-adopt').attr('data-id', data[i].id);

    petsRow.append(petTemplate.html());
  }
});

 return App.bindEvents();
},


 bindEvents: function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-list', App.listAdopt); //Button in index.html for rendering to list.html page
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-listlist', App.listfun); //Button in list.html page for displaying adopted pets.
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-home', App.homepage);//Button in list.html for rendering to index.html
 },


 homepage: function(){
    window.location.href ="../index.html";
   },


 listAdopt: function(){
   window.location.href = "../list.html";
    },

 listfun: function(adopters, account){

  //Code to display adopted pets in list.html
   }

 };

$(function() {
 $(window).load(function() {
 console.log('Inside window Load function');
 App.init();
 });
 });
```

So once it is redirected to 'list.html' it gives a blank page and on clicking a button will perform an event and display adopted pets.

When page is rendered to 'list.html', **app.js** is loaded again from App.init() since I have specified the script in 'list.html' and 'index.html'.I need same **js** file on each html page.

Is there any other way by which adopted pets could be displayed in 'list.html' once page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I would add something on jquery document ready

```
 Your code

$( document ).ready(function() {
App.listfun
});
```

Comment: Thanks...Where I have place this code?  I replaced  `$(document).on('click', '.btn-listlist', App.listfun);` . But it doesn't work